# How to initialize Pybind11 array with zeros in C++?

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm new to C++ and Pybind11. Is it possible to initialize a multidimensional pybind array `py::array_t` with zeros? In C++, I can do `float marr[10][10] = {};`.

I'm creating a pybind array as follows. I can fill in zeros using nested for loops, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way.

```
size_t N = 3;
size_t M = 4;
py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style> arr({N, M});

// How to initialize arr with zeros?
```

Does pybind initialize with zeros automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, and maybe there is a constructor that takes a fill value somewhere, but I couldn't find it either. Somewhere here?
https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/1874f8fa8767179ab8f8c645a6e8c8c4e4a7c486/include/pybind11/numpy.h

For now I worked around the issue by constructing the array, then using ellipsis indexing:

```
py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style> a({3, 4});
a[py::make_tuple(py::ellipsis())] = 0.f;
```

So basically it's the cpp alternative for this python code:

```
a = np.empty([3,4],dtype=np.float32)
a[...] = 0
```

This way you can make an array with a fill value (zero in the example).

See more at
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html?#ellipsis